# Terraform vsphere provider not working for vsphere 7.0

Tags: terraform, vsphere

We are managing our Infrastructure by terraform and recently we migrated to vsphere 7.0 but it seems that the provider is not tested for vsphere 7. How soon will the terraform vsphere provider be compatible with vsphere 7? Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the project on github, you can see that there are still a couple of open issues with **Vsphere 7**, although others have been solved:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vsphere/labels/vSphere%207